# The number of microstates is independent of energy... no way right?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was reading Blundell's Thermodynamics book, and there is one part in his 'derivation' of the Boltzman distribution that is bothering me a lot, so I was hoping someone with more experience could explain it.

On page 37 (attatched bellow) is where my problem lies...

[image]

So, yeah basically he says that we can assume that each possible energy level of the system (here system refers to non reservoir body) has only one microstate, but I don't understand how you can just assume it...

Because on literally the previous page, while deriving the condition for two objects to be in thermal equillibrium
$\frac{d \ln \Omega_1(E_1)}{dE_1} = \frac{d \ln \Omega_2(E_2)}{dE_2}$

He had used the fact that the number of microstates of a two body system is $\Omega_1(E_1) \times \Omega_2(E_2)$ but now we are assuming each possible energy level of the system has just one microstate...

And then he says that the probability that the system has energy $\epsilon$ (assuming the energy of reservoir + system is initially $E$) is:

$P(\epsilon) \propto \Omega(E-\epsilon) \times 1$ because we assumed each energy level of system has only one microstate...

In my mind, the number of microstates of system $\Omega(\epsilon)$ should be very important, maybe even more important than the reservoir $\Omega(E-\epsilon)$ term because the reservoir is so huge, there is basically no difference in the energy of the reservoir...

So the probability should infact be:

$P(\epsilon) \propto \Omega(E-\epsilon) \times \Omega(\epsilon)$

which would imply that the probability of Boltzman distribution is actually

$P(\epsilon) \propto \Omega(\epsilon) \times \exp(-\frac{\epsilon}{kT})$

which is obviously not correct... could someone please explain what I'm missing here...

Comment: You are misreading the text. The  microstates can have any energy. It is the *entire ensemble*  that has a fixed total energy. This fixed energy is the sum of all the energies of the occupied microstates.

Comment: @mikestone i understand that the microstates can have any energy and that the entire thing (system+reservoir)has a fixed energy(which I wrote as E),what I am discussing is the opposite,how many microstates have a fixed enrgy $\epsilon$ (as i said this is how he derived the 1/kt = d/dE (ln omega) thing in the book), he says in this case we can assume that each possible energy has just one microstate with that energy, but I'm saying what if this is not the case, like what if some $\epsilon_0$ is such that lots of microstates have that energy, which is why i think omega(epsilon) term is needed...

Comment: I think that must be convenience. The small system does not care about the details of the large one --- but I do not see why $P(\epsilon)\propto \Omega(\epsilon) e^{-\epsilon/kT}$ is "not correct". Is that not the usual Boltzman factor?

Comment: @mikestone the usual boltzman factor is $P(\epsilon) \propto \Omega(E)exp\frac{-\epsilon}{kt}$ (so E instead of epsilon, and since E is constant we can ignore the epsilon E term... sorry but i did not understand your comment... could you please explain what you mean by the small system not carning about the larger one, like we are just interested in probabilities here, and the probability presumably should care about the larger system (or the smaller systems omega(epsilon) term here)